# How mark my Android Service to did not stop by user?

Tags: android, service

I have a service in my android application and I need that it never stop.
How to mark my service so the user could never stop it?
If the user goes to: "Setting - Applications - Running Services - My Service" and click on STOP, my service should not be stopped.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent stopping a service. The same way you cannot prevent somebody from force closing your app. Even if it were possible, the user could still kill your service by uninstalling your app. Why do you want the service not to be stopped?

On second thought you could have two services that monitor each other periodically by checking [ActivityManager.getRunningServices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29). When one service is killed the other could restart it. This would probably be considered malicious activity on your part, and you would likely receive very negative reviews.

Comment: My service sends Geolocation (lat and long) of device in a given time interval.

Comment: Service is the way to go, but there isn't any reason to prevent the user from killing it. Android already warns the user that killing a service can cause the app to malfunction.

Comment: Ok thanks. I go use your idea of use two services.
Very, very thanks!!

Comment: This will not work, as if the user force-stops the app, neither service will be running anymore, all scheduled alarms with `AlarmManager` will be removed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to sidestep the obvious question:

Why would you want to do this?

and give you a workable answer.  You need two services.  Each one monitors the other.  If the user kills service A, service B restarts it.  If the user kills service B, service A restarts it.

The services will have to be very quick to respond and relaunch the service.  This would prevent the user from killing them both at once.  So you'll need to design a very quick heartbeat service, but it should be possible.  Of course, this will not prevent the user from simply uninstalling your app.

Comment: This application do not be uninstalled because is a corporate application, and only used in corporate device (phone or tablet).
My application send the location of this device.

Comment: This will not work, as if the user force-stops the app, neither service will be running anymore, all scheduled alarms with AlarmManager will be removed, etc.

Comment: I agree - force stopping the app will stop all services.  This solution would only work if the user force stopped a service, not the whole app.  To work around that, then you've got to have two apps, each with a service as I described.  Since this is for a corporate device, requiring that isn't out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

"I fight for the users".

I would be frustrated with an app that didn't let me cancel a service it was running.

I can't think of a use case in which an *app* (not something in the system) should prevent the user from cancelling something. You should, of course, notify users if the service isn't running, and provide an easy way to restart it.